# Get maximum number of dots in a string-property of a class in a List<T>?

Tags: c#, string, list, linq-to-objects

My object (`KoClass`) has a string property named `Title`. This property can have a string in a format `01.001.0001.003`. It can contain up to ten elements, separated with `.`.

How can I calculate, how many `.` are present in the longest string?

```
List<KoClass> kok = new List<KoClass>();
kok.FillData();

int maxLength = ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to find the maximum-number of dots in one of your objects' titles? You can use LINQ:

```
int maxDotNumber = kok.Max(k => k.Title.Count(c => c == '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The poster is asking "how many . are present in the longest string?", so what I did first is using LINQ to get the object with the longest title, then count how many dots are in that title.

```
 int dotNumberInLongestString = kok.OrderByDescending(k => k.Title.Length)
                                   .First().Title
                                   .Where(c => c == '.').Count();
```

Comment: Please consider adding dialog to your answers.

Comment: your answer is considered 'Code only answer'. Please add some more explantations.